# Automatically convert any given video to a format that can be posted on Instagram

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Imagine I am given any video format, what is the most optimal way to convert the video to a format that can be posted on Instagram?

The video format must conform to this
[Instagram Video Specifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#video-specifications)

I'm looking at FFMPeg but I just felt I should ask first for probably existing solutions in the NodeJS community before re-inventing the wheel.

My tech stack is NodeJS.

Please note that I have attempted to search for solutions with no results.

Any ideas on this would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to do it?
Did you find a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Yes, FFMPEG command-line would be my preferred option. But, run it as a background worker.

This is what I would do:

1. For each video required, post the source URL to a queue (Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, etc...)
2. Create a background worker process (Docker container?) to pop each message off
3. Run the file through FFMPEG
4. Upload the result to Instagram

If there are no messages, just wait patiently in the background worker.

Generally it's a good idea to separate front-end API's from back-end workers so they can scale independently.